# How to add tooltip on mouse hover on autocomplete options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have written a function which implements autocomplete on the input field. In this function I am making an ajax call to get the data and then binding it to the input field and every thing is working fine. My new requirement is to show the email id when we hover the mouse on user name. I have searched for the events on the jQuery [site](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) but didn't find any event or method for mouse hover. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function AutopopulateUsers(id, url) {
    //url='@Url.Action("GetUserByName", "Home")'
    $(id).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { name: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.rows, function (item) {                       
                        return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name, info: $.trim(item.NetId) + '#' + item.UserId + '#' + item.Email };
                    }));
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $(this).focus();
            $(id).val(i.item.value)
            var data = i.item.info.split('#');
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $(id).attr("data-userid", data[1]);
                $(id).attr("data-netid", data[0]);
                $(id).attr("data-email", data[2]);

                $(id).data("userid", data[1]);
                $(id).data("netid", data[0]);
                $(id).data("email", data[2]);
            }
            return false;
        },
        close: function () {
            var userId = $(id).data("userid");
            if (userId == 0 || userId == null || userId == '' || userId == undefined) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        },
        minLength: 3
    });
}
```

Comment: Use : `focus: function( event, ui ) {
          $(".ui-autocomplete > li").attr("title", ui.item.Email );
      }` :

Comment: Next time please post a [mcve] - we do not need the ajax function since it works. Just the RELEVANT HTML, RELEVANT JS, necessary framwork(s) from CDN and RELEVANT CSS in a stack snippet (icon: `[<>]`). [BUT FIRST search your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+ui+autocomplete+hover+tooltip). It took a few seconds to find a perfect dupe.

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant -- It works like a charm. Thanks a lot. Just tweak the code little bit to get the email id.

Comment: @mplungjan - Sure, will take care of it in future. Thanks.

Comment: @Obraine glad to help. A dupe link was found and added. you can check there for some other options